# Should I use JMeter With Selenium And junit for load and performance testing of Web applications?

Tags: performance, selenium, jmeter, junit4

I want to Use java code with selenium and junit into jmeter to tests application performance, because i guess that the record doesnt allow test visibility and maintainability!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on 2 factors:

1. What load you're trying to achieve (how many concurrent virtual users you need)
2. What hardware do you have

Looking for example into [Firefox 72.0.2 system requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/72.0.2/system-requirements/):

- 1 CPU core with support of SSE2 instructions per browser instance
- 2 GB of RAM per browser instance

It means that for Selenium test assuming 100 virtual users you will need 101 CPU cores and 200 gigabytes of RAM.

The same load you can simulate using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers with a couple of CPU cores and gigabytes of RAM.

So if you have access to unlimited hardware at no cost you can re-use your tests, but if you want to keep the load test footprint at minimum you should consider converting the tests. Just make sure to [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

Comment: If I choose using jmeter Http request i will need :  1 CPU core with support of SSE2 instructions per browser instance
2 GB of RAM per browser instance??

Answer (score 0):

though Jmeter with Selenium is a very good feature , i would recommend not to go with that approach because. Jmeter itself consumes a lot of resources when you try to run tests for multiple threads.
So, when you try to run Jmeter with selenium it is going to consume a lot of resources, which is a very costly approach.

It is better to use HTTP Requests for Jmeter(performance and load related testing).